# Why jquery ajax post request get error in yii2?

Tags: ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

js:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/site/updateuserdata',
        method: 'POST',
        //async: true,
        //cache:false,
        data: {
            'type': 'sort'
            //val: val
            //csrfParam: csrfToken
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error by ajax');
        },
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert('success by ajax');
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['updateuserdata'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    // 'roles' => ['*'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'updateuserdata' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionUpdateuserdata()
{
    /*if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $message = 'Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено';
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => $message
        ];
        return $response;
    }*/
    $f = fopen('testajax.txt','a+');
    fwrite($f, 'ajax: '.(isset($_POST['type'])?$_POST['type']:'error'));
    fclose($f);
    if(isset($_POST['type']))
        return $_POST['type'];
    else return 'error1';
    // return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer, 302, FALSE);
}
```

yii.js:

```
function initRedirectHandler() {
    // handle AJAX redirection
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr) {
        var url = xhr && xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Redirect');
        alert(url);  //my code
        if (url) {
            window.location.assign(url);
        }
    });
}
```

I see first alert(ajax error) "error by ajax" and then alert(yii.js) "..../site/updateuserdata...", why ajax error? File `testajax.txt` not create.
I tried comment `'updateuserdata' => ['post'],` and get error too.

Updated.

Also, tried:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'updateuserdata') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

and uncomment csrf parameters in ajax.
And 'error' return status 302(jqXHR.status).

dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: Please remove from your question all the _r_

Comment: ok, done. remove all r

Comment: the `success` callback has only one parameter `data` so change the `success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {` to `success: function(data) {` and to see the actual error you should `alert(errorThrown)` inside the `error` callback

Comment: @user15445 And also, you have to include `csrfParam: csrfToken` in to your `ajax` call, overwize you will get `400 Bad Request` response.

Comment: i tried with csrf(i know that) and function 'success' return all parameters for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find problem, it's stupid problem:

```
url: '/mag/updateuserdata/',
```

i have in 'urlManager':

```
'suffix' => '/',
```

i think this added for all, but not.....

Answer (score -1):

Cause you commented

```
//csrfParam: csrfToken
```

from your ajax `js` file you have `400` http status code in your ajax.

So you can solve it in two way:

**one:** disable `csrf validation` by adding

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

in your `actionUpdateuserdata` method.

**two:** add `csrf token` and `csrf param` to your ajax.

print this code in your js, where you commented it.

```
Yii::$app->request->csrfParam . ':' . Yii::$app->request->csrfToken
```

then your request sent successfully and if you have other error you must check your code.

Comment: See update. And ajax in js file(asset), php function cant write there. By the way csrf send automaticaly if have meta tags, right?